# Speed up menu switching speed in windows 11 new UI (e.g. settings)

Tags: windows-11

In the windows 11 settings app or task manager, we can click on the left to switch between different categories. When we switch, we see a visual effect.

Sometimes the visual effect is too slow. Is there a way to speed it up? Apparently that could not be a hardware performance issue - how performance-demanding can it possibly be to merely display menus?!